# How to delete multiple files in Fujifilm Xpro-1?

Tags: memory-card, fujifilm-xpro1, delete

Camera: Fujifilm's Xpro-1

Coming back from a trip I had ~300 raw photos in the 16Gb memory card, already saved in the computer, when I went shooting some more. I forgot to format the card after the transfer. In the middle of this adventure, I got the message that the card was full, which led me to delete many earlier photos from the card. I did it one by one, as I couldn't find a way to select them in the grid view. Is there such an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlight pictures and press MENU/OK to select or deselect (pictures that in a photobook or print order are shown by S). When the operation is complete, press DISP/BACK to display a confirmation dialog, then highlight OK and press MENU/OK.

I suggest to read page 65 of the manual.

Comment: that seems useful, but how do you highlight in the first place?

Comment: ok, so apparently i need to press |menu| first, then select |erase>selected frames| and then I can finally highlight photos with a green tick.